# Regression macros in excel with increasing rows of data

Tags: excel, vba, regression

Basically, I recorded a macros in excel to run a regression based on the data sets I have. However, I will be adding new data in more rows. For example, I have 16 rows of Y and 16 rows of X. In the following day, I will be adding 1 more row of Y and X. However, my macros will only run the regression for the data in the first 16 rows. How can I program my macros such that it takes into account all the data rows that exist? My macros code is:

```
Sub Regression()
'
' Regression Macro
'

'
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("REGRESSION").Select
ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
 Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$16"), _
    ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$F$16"), False, True, , "REGRESSION", False, _
    False, False, False, , False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to change this

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$16")
```

to

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

This way the `16` will always be replaced with the last used row number.

Note same idea applies with the F Column

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$F$" & Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping out! Do have a problem though because now only F16 is replaced with the last used row number. However, I also need to take into account increase in column B to E. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: @LeeGaoYi I think that your original question should be solved now. I am sorry but I dont understand your above problem. What do you mean by `increase in column B to E`? `Range("B1:F" & lastRow)` selects all cells in between B1 and last row in F. Try `Range("B1:F" & Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlup).ROw).Interior.Color = Rgb(255,0,0)` in a new Sub and see what has been selected